# Find out which function is a better fit for data

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression

I've used R's non-linear regression function `nls` to find estimates for two different functions that both give a reasonably good plot for my data. However, I'm supposed to find out which one of the two functions is a better fit for my data. How can I do that? I've already made QQplots for the residuals of both functions, and both show that the residuals are normally distributed. Are there any other ways to check which one of my two functions fits my data best?

Comment: If they have the same number of parameters, wouldn't sum of squared residuals be one indicator of closer fit?

Comment: The functions do not have the same number of parameters, so that would not work. Is there any other way to find out which one fits better?

Comment: That information should be in your question (along with anything you can say about why you seek a better fit and why you're comparing the particular models you're looking at).